# Difference between Orthogonally Diagonalizable and just Diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to confirm if my understanding of the differences between the two is correct. BOTH of them need N distinct eigenvectors Right?(Suppose A = nxn matrix). Is there any other restriction imposed on orthogonally diagonalizable matrices with respect to each eigenvalue's multiplicity? 
My textbook says for just diagonalizable, dimension of eigen space for a particular eigen value k is less than or equal to mutlplicity of k but for orthogonally diagonalizable it has to be equal. Why? Why is there this difference? Doesn't diagonalizable already imply that dim(eigenspace for k) = multiplicity?

Comment: As an aside, in the complex world, a matrix $A$ is unitarily diagonalisable **iff** it is normal ($A A^* = A^* A$). Note that **any** diagonalisable matrix has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is diagonalizable if and only if there is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. This implies that the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ (the number of linearly independent eigenvectors associated to $\lambda$) is the same as the algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue (the power in which $(x - \lambda)$ appears in the factorization of the characteristic polynomial $p_A(x)$ of $A$).

A matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is orthogonally diagonalizable if and only if there is an **orthonormal** basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. This is a stronger condition in the sense that any orthogonally diagonalizable matrix is clearly diagonalizable but the converse does not hold.

In particular, both for the case of diagonalization and orthogonal diagonalization the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue must be the same as the algebraic multiplicity but in the case of orthogonal diagonalization this is not enough. The difference between regular diagonalization and orthogonal diagonalization is that in the case of an orthogonally diagonalizable matrix, the eigenspaces associated to distinct eigenvalues are **orthogonal** to each other while if $A$ is merely diagonalizable, this needs not be the case.