# Geometrically, what is unique about the mapping of an orthogonally diagonizable matrix (versus non-orthogonal)?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, intuition, orthogonality, diagonalization

Geometrically, what is the difference between a diagonizable matrix and an orthogonally diagonizable matrix?

I understand the difference algebraically, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050763/difference-between-orthogonally-diagonalizable-and-just-diagonalizable) and many other places.  But I'm struggling to see the difference geometrically: both will *not* rotate (assuming the field is the reals), but will stretch by different amounts along different axes (Wikipedia calls this a [inhomogenous dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhomogeneous_dilation)).  Graphically, I can't see the difference between, say, a circle or ellipse dilated inhomogenously along orthogonal axes versus non-orthogonal axes: in either case, it will [remain an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498799/what-shape-do-we-get-when-we-shear-an-ellipse-and-more-generally-do-affine-tra).

Comment: @AnneBauval As far as I can tell, even a inhomogeneous dilation along _orthogonal_ axes won't preserve rectangles, if the axes are not the principal ones of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

In fact: There is no geometric difference!  Every plane transform of a diagonizable matrix is geometrically congurent to an orthogonally diagonizable matrix, via the polar decomposition.  See [Conjecture: Every shear transformation of the plane is congruent to a dilation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703905/conjecture-every-shear-transformation-of-the-plane-is-congruent-to-a-dilation) .

(I'm using *congruence* in its geometric meaning: $F$ is congruent to $F'$ if there is an isometry sending $F \mapsto F'$.)