# Conjecture: Every shear transformation of the plane is congruent to a dilation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, conjectures, geometric-transformation

I conjecture that every shear transformation of the plane is geometrically congruent to an orthogonal dilation of the plane.  That is, in Euclidean geometry of the plane, if I shear figure $F$, I can produce a geometrically congruent figure $F'$ via orthogonal dilation.

Is my conjecture correct? If so, what is the orthogonal dilation $D$ congruent to $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \tan \theta \\ 0  & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$  Since shears have determinant 1, I believe it must be of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & 0 \\ 0  & \frac 1 \alpha \end{bmatrix},$$ but can't figure out $\alpha$ as a function of $\theta$ (or of $\lambda$ in the general case above).

Likewise, consider [image] - what dilation, along any axes, can produce it? I haven't been able to sketch one.

The support for this conjecture is via linear algebra; below are the definitions and support:

---

### Definitions

*[Shear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping)* means $S: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2, S = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \lambda \\ 0  & 1\end{bmatrix}$ or $S = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ \lambda  & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

*[Congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry))* is defined: a set of points $F$ is congruent to $F'$ if there is an isometry (preserving distance, angles, and colinearity) that sends $F \to F'$.  Note that congruent does *not imply* matrix similarity: it a geometric property related by isometry.

*Orthogonal dilation* means an arbitrary set of axes is chosen, each orthogonal to the rest, and the plane is scaled by a (perhaps different) constant along each.  This is precisely the matrices of the form $PDP^{-1}$ where $P$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal.

### Conjecture

I conjecture that for any shear $S$ there exists an orthogonal dilation $D$ such that for all figures $F$, $S(F) \cong D(F)$.

### Support

Every real 2x2 matrix can be decomposed into a polar decomposition $A = PU$ where $U$ is orthogonal diagonizable and $P$ is an orthogonal matrix (and therefore an isometry).

This implies the conjecture and also something related: Every dilation along non-orthogonal axes is congruent to a dilation along congruent axes.

---

**Background:** While trying to determine [Geometrically, what is unique about the mapping of an orthogonally diagonizable matrix (versus non-orthogonal)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698953/geometrically-what-is-unique-about-the-mapping-of-an-orthogonally-diagonizable?noredirect=1#comment9948998_4698953) , I came to the conclusion that **there is no difference**: every diagonalizable transform is geometrically congruent to an orthogonally diagonalizable geometric transform!

Further background to this conjecture is at [Is every symmetric matrix in $\mathbb R^n$ a (non-uniform) stretch?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4696702/is-every-symmetric-matrix-in-mathbb-rn-a-non-uniform-stretch) .

Comment: Why are you not considering $\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}$ to be a shear? I do not follow your argument at all; shears have eigenvalue $1$ with algebraic multiplicity $2$ but geometric multiplicity $1$. How can these be conjugate to a diagonal matrix of any sort?

Comment: @TedShifrin: I don't think the OP's notion of "congruence" need be the same as conjugacy as we ordinarily understand it.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've used the geometric definition of congruence, from Euclidean geometry.  My conjecture concerns Euclidean geometric properties, which I'm attempting to prove via linear algebra.  Re definition of shear: I felt it simpler to focus on a subset of simpler cases (horizontal shear by an angle $\theta$), which I believe capture everything, but have expanded the definition to include your case as well.

Comment: Your description of what you call "orthogonal dilation"is incorrect if you require the axes to be mutually orthogonal. It is not enough to require $P$ to be invertible: you must require that the columns be pairwise orthogonal; equivalently, that it be unitary (if over $\mathbb{C}$) or orthogonal (over $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Also, the paragraph that starts "I conjecture" after tge definition of orthogonal dilation mentions $D$ but never uses it, and uses $C$ but never says what $C$ is.

Comment: It would be nice if you learned, and used, the standard terminology (such as "orthogonally diagonalizable") instead of making up your own using terminology that already has different standard meanings. In other words, if you tried to work in the world every one else inhabits, instead of one of your own creation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks, I've revised accordingly.  Regarding terminology: When thinking of a new (to me) concept, I don't yet know that it _has_ a standard terminology.  The only way I can learn it is by defining the concept, asking questions about it, and learning from people, such as yourself, who know more math than I do.

Comment: And last time, I noted the correct terminology (orthogonally diagonalizable), but you decided against using it here, instead making up yet another new term ("orthogonal dilation"). So you do not seem to be actually learning the standard terminology, even when it is explained and offered to you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My understanding is that "diagonalizable" is a term regarding _matrices_ while "dilation" is the term regarding _figures in the plane_.  Of course, the two correspond, but are not synonymous.  What is the correct term when discussing transformation of geometric figures in the plane? Wikipedia uses "dilation", but it sounds like you feel that it is incorrect.

Comment: You expressly defined "orthogonal dilation" as "precisely the matrices of the form $PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal and $P$ is [orthogonal]". So... you **are** talking about matrices/linear transformations. Where does this distinction come from, then? You **are** talking about linear transformations, and you **are** aware of the correct terminology, and you **are** purposefully avoiding it in favor of one of your own invention. What you describe as "orthogonal dilation", *per your own words* is nothing more and nothing less than an orthogonally diagonalizable linear transformation/matrix.

Comment: I'm at least somewhat confused. You know about the polar decomposition of a matrix. So $S=WP$ for some positive definite matrix $P$ (which is necessarily orthogonally diagonalizable), and an orthogonal operator $W$ (which is in particular a rigid motion). So why are you "conjecturing"? $S(F)$ is congruent to $P(F)$, since we can obtain $S(F)$ by applying the rigid motion $W$ to $P(F)$. Is this really a "conjecture" that this happens, or are you actually asking about what $P$ will be for the case of your particular $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call an "orthogonal dilation" is what is normally called an "orthogonally diagonalizable transformation" (or matrix).

TL;DR: the numbers $\alpha$ and $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ are the [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A$.

As you note, the polar decomposition of a matrix says:

**Theorem.** For any real square matrix $A$ there exists an orthogonal matrix $W$ and a positive semidefinite matrix $P$ such that $A=WP$. Moreover, if $A$ is invertible then the representation is unique.

A positive semidefinite matrix is a matrix of the form $B^TB$ for some square matrix $B$; in particular, positive semidefinite matrices are always symmetric, and therefore orthogonally diagonalizable.

This says that **every** real square matrix can be decomposed as an orthogonally diagonalizable matrix followed by an orthogonal matrix (which is necessarily a rigid motion); this rigid motion realizes your "congruence".

So you already know that your "conjecture" holds; it seems that you are just trying to figure out what the diagonal matrix (or perhaps what the positive definite matrix $P$?) is.

If we let $A$ be a matrix of the form
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \lambda\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right),$$
then $A=WP$ will mean that $A$ corresponds to an orthogonally diagonalizable matrix (with positive eigenvalues, in fact), followed by an orthogonal linear transformation (which is necessarily a rigid motion).

Since your $A$ is invertible, the representation is unique, and we can obtain an explicit form for $P$ using the singular value decomposition of $A$. We can also calculate the value of $\alpha$ (in your notation at the top) in terms of $\lambda$ straightforwardly enough.

Namely, if $A=U\Sigma V^T$ is a singular value decomposition for $A$, then $W=UV^T$ and $P=V\Sigma V^T$ will be the desired expression. Here $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the singular values of $A$.

The singular values of $A$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. We have
$$A^TA = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
\lambda & 1\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \lambda\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \lambda\\
\lambda & 1+\lambda^2
\end{array}\right).$$
The eigenvalues are then the roots of $t^2 - (\lambda^2+2)t+1$, which are
$$\frac{\lambda^2 + 2 \pm \lambda\sqrt{\lambda^2+4}}{2}.$$
So the matrix $\Sigma$ will be $\Sigma=\mathrm{Diag}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$, where
$$\begin{align*}
\alpha_1 &= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda^2+2 + |\lambda|\sqrt{\lambda^2+4}}{2}},\\
\alpha_2 &= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda^2+2-|\lambda|\sqrt{\lambda^2+4}}{2}}
\end{align*}$$
(following the convention that the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$ must be non-increasing in size). It is straighforward to verify that $\alpha_1\alpha_2=1$.

Symmetrically, if $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ \lambda&1\end{array}\right)$, then
$$A^TA=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1+\lambda^2 & \lambda\\
\lambda & 1\end{array}\right).$$
This has the same characteristic polynomial, hence the same eigenvalues, hence the same singular values, you again get $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

Comment: Clear and direct as usual! As to why I called it a "conjecture" and not a proof: I was exploring shears from a Euclidean geometry perspective, and came to the conclusion that, based on polar decomposition, they must be congruent to dilations (the term I've seen in geometry texts).  This was surprising, and I wasn't able to sketch such a congruence, find a reference to it, or find the dilation needed, but the polar decomposition seems to show it must exist; hence I termed it a conjecture.  Thank you for verifying it, and for showing how to find the dilation needed.